# How to fetch the list of Estimate records using SuiteScript in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I am unable to fetch the List of Estimate records using SuiteScript in Netsuite. I have used the same script for the CUSTOMER records and it is working fine but when I am using the same for ESTIMATE records but it is not working.

Here is my SuiteScript code:

```
define(['N/https','N/query'], function (https, query) {
    /**
     * @NApiVersion 2.1
     * @NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
     */
    const exports = {};

    function onAction(context)
    {
      // Create a query definition on estimate records
        let myEstimateQuery = query.create({
            type: query.Type.ESTIMATE
        });
      // Create conditions for the query
        let firstCondition = myEstimateQuery.createCondition({
            fieldId: 'Opportunity',
            operator: query.Operator.EMPTY_NOT
        });
        myEstimateQuery.condition = myEstimateQuery.and(firstCondition);

        // Create query columns
    myEstimateQuery.columns = [
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'id'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'custbody_quote_internal_id'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'tranid'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'externalid'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'currency'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'duedate'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'enddate'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'startdate'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'subtotal'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'custbody_tran_term_in_months'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'custbody_end_user'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'custbody_qumu_deployment_type'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'custbody_qumu_orig_renewal'
        }),
        myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
            fieldId: 'custbody_qumu_target_renewal'
        })
     ];
    // Run the query
      let resultSet = myEstimateQuery.run();
      log.debug('resultSet>> ', resultSet);
      log.debug('resultSet.length>> ',  resultSet.results.length);
      log.debug('resultSet.results>> ',  resultSet.results);

    }
    exports.onAction = onAction;
    return exports;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues you'll need to fix:

1. `query.Type.ESTIMATE` does not exist; you need `query.Type.TRANSACTION` as the Estimate/Quote record is a Transaction.
2. Add a condition for the specific `recordtype` to get only Estimates.
3. Add the new condition to your conditions list.
4. `subtotal` is not a valid query column. You can find the valid columns by looking up "transaction" in the Records Catalog under `Setup > Records Catalog`.

```js
    const myEstimateQuery = query.create({
      type: query.Type.TRANSACTION // Fix 1: Use TRANSACTION instead of ESTIMATE
    });
    
    // Fix 2: Add a new filter for Estimate recordtype
    const firstCondition = myEstimateQuery.createCondition({
      fieldId: 'recordtype',
      operator: query.Operator.IS,
      values: ['estimate']
    });
    const secondCondition = myEstimateQuery.createCondition({
      fieldId: 'opportunity',
      operator: query.Operator.EMPTY_NOT
    });

    // Fix 3: Add the new filter
    myEstimateQuery.condition = myEstimateQuery.and([firstCondition, secondCondition]);

    // ...

    // Fix 4: Use an appropriate, valid query column instead of subtotal
    myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
      fieldId: 'foreigntotal'
    }),

    // ...
```

FWIW if you happen to be more familiar with SQL, you can write this same query a bit more concisely using the `runSuiteQL` method instead:

```js
const myEstimateQuery = query.runSuiteQL({
  query: `
    SELECT
      currency,
      custbody_end_user,
      custbody_qumu_deployment_type,
      custbody_qumu_orig_renewal,
      custbody_qumu_target_renewal,
      custbody_quote_internal_id,
      custbody_tran_term_in_months,
      duedate,
      enddate,
      externalid,
      foreigntotal,
      startdate,
      tranid,
      custbody
    FROM
      transaction
    WHERE
      recordtype = 'estimate' AND
      opportunity IS NOT NULL
  `
});
```

Comment: Hi @erictgrubaugh,

I am very thankful to you for the response, 
Your answer is absolutely correct to get the NetSuite estimate records and it's working fine. But still, I am unable to get the 'subtotal' even I have used 'foreigntotal' for that but its working for 'Total' not for 'Subtotal'.

myEstimateQuery.createColumn({
      fieldId: 'foreigntotal'     //working fine for get the 'Total'
    }),

It will be very helpful if it is possible to get the 'subtotal' directly through the query.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of what `subtotal` means? In general, you can add any number of subtotal lines to any transactions as Subtotal is a standard Item that will sum up the amounts of all the previous lines. You could peruse around the Records Catalog for an appropriate value, or you may have to calculate it.